# Logic Apps failed triggers

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic app that is triggered whenever there's a new record in SQL table (running in 1 minutes interval).
The trigger sometimes fails because of timeout. It connects through datagateway to on-premise database and from time to time it happens the server doesn't respond within 2 minutes. Now, can anyone please help me answer my following question:

In case there are new items added while datagateway server is down, will following successful trigger pick all the new items that were added to SQL table while it was down or will new records be ignored?

I can't find answer for this in documentation, does anyone have previous experience with it and can confirm how it works please?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test with gateway but test with add new items when logic app was disabled. The logic app will be triggered for the new items when logic app enabled again.

So I think your logic app will also be triggered for the new items added when gateway server was down in the next success trigger.